# Plot trend lines (not planes or smooth surfaces) on interactive, 3-dimensional graphs in R

Tags: r

I want to plot a trend line (not a plane or a smooth surface) on an interactive, 3-dimensional graph in R.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
library (car)
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:100 + rnorm(100, 5, 5)
y <- x + rnorm(100, 10, 20)
z <- y + rnorm(100, 1, 10)
scatter3d(x = x, y = y, z = z, surface = F)
```

Essentially, I want to plot a trend line on this graph that goes through the region of maximum variability in this cloud of points. This trend line is, of course, the first principal components axis. I know how to perform a principal components analysis on these data:

```
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
prcomp(df, center = T, scale. = T)
```

How can I plot the principal components axes on this scatterplot?

(I'm certainly open to using different packages for creating interactive, 3-dimensional scatterplots. I started to use the `scatter3d` function in the `car` package because the `plotly` package was giving me trouble - I kept receiving the `WebGL is not supported by your browser - visit https://get.webgl.org for more info` message when I tried to create 3-dimensional plots using the `plotly` function.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok hopefully I get this correct. To plot the principal components you need the eigenvectors, and this is given in `$rotation`. First we set up the 3D plot and calculate the principal component:

```
library(rgl)
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:100 + rnorm(100, 5, 5)
y <- x + rnorm(100, 10, 20)
z <- y + rnorm(100, 1, 10)
M = cbind(x,y,z)
pca = prcomp(df, center = T, scale. = T)
```

We plot the points:

```
plot3d(M)
```

Since you scaled the principal component, we need find the means (or center) of your x,y,z and plot the PCs from there. And since the PC is an eigenvector, I simply plotted a segment from the centre to around 100*eigenvector:

```
centers = colMeans(M)
PC1 = rbind(centers,centers+100*pca$rotation[,1])
colnames(PC1) = c("x","y","z")
segments3d(PC1,col="blue",lwd=2)

PC2 = rbind(centers,centers+100*pca$rotation[,2])
colnames(PC2) = c("x","y","z")
segments3d(PC2,col="orange",lwd=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Following up on StupidWolf's excellent answer, here's a way to get the lines to stop at maximum and minimum values of your data, instead of arbitrarily selecting multipliers such as 100:

```
PC1 <- rbind(pca$center + min(pca$x[, 1]) * pca$rotation[, 1], pca$center + max(pca$x[, 1]) * pca$rotation[, 1])
colnames(PC1) = c("x", "y", "z")
segments3d(PC1, col = 1 , lwd = 2)

PC2 <- rbind(pca$center + min(pca$x[, 2]) * pca$rotation[, 2], pca$center + max(pca$x[, 2]) * pca$rotation[, 2])
colnames(PC2) = c("x", "y", "z")
segments3d(PC2, col = 2 , lwd = 2)

PC1 <- rbind(pca$center + min(pca$x[, 3]) * pca$rotation[, 3], pca$center + max(pca$x[, 3]) * pca$rotation[, 3])
colnames(PC1) = c("x", "y", "z")
segments3d(PC1, col = 3 , lwd = 2)
```